# Python worker process execute the script before running worker function?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocess

I have a python script:

```
import os
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

print("my PID:")
print(os.getpid())


def worker():
    print("I am a worker!")
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit(1)


def main():
    Process(target=worker, args=()).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when I execute it using

```
python3 -u "/dir/demo.py"
```

I got the following results:

```
my PID:
91058
my PID:
91082
I am a worker!
```

Why doesn't the worker process execute the worker function directly? Why it prints its PID which code is not in its target function? I am confused!

I thought the results will be

```
my PID:
{the PID of main process.}
I am a worker!
```

Comment: When i execute your code, i exactly got the result intended that display the pid then "i am worker!". Try tro clear your terminal before running your code.

Comment: @Bloodbee I have asked several friends to execute the code, and all of them return the PID of the main process and worker process!

Comment: Isn't it what you want and what you code do?

Comment: No, the worker process printed its PID is confusing me. The two print statement is out scope worker function. An explanation is needed.

Comment: I confirm you that i've got only one print statement for the PID. Try to close/reopen your terminal and run your code again maybe?

Comment: I have tried according to your suggestions but got the same results.  We got different outputs. That's the problem!